# Find point of difference in two Google protobufs

Tags: c++, protobuf-c

I'm comparing two very large protobufs to figure out if there is a difference and if there is the point of divergence.
I'm using MessageDifferencer which points out that there are differences between the two protobufs.
I've been eye-balling the string dump of protobufs using diff -y tool (side by side comparison) which shows wherever there is a difference it's due to different organization of the fields of the messages. In other words the fields are the same, only different in their order of print.
Is there a way to find where the two protobufs are different?

Comment: Serialization order of protobuf fields [is not defined](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order), so they might be in any order in the encoded string. I'd recommend to use the [MessageDifferencer class](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h#L123) instead to find differences between two protobufs (first call  `ReportDifferencesToString` / `ReportDifferencesTo`, then [`Compare`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h#L592-L599))

Comment: Thanks for that note. I did try to use Compare and ReportDifferencesToString. Couldn't get it to compile because of static function issue. It seems like I have to instantiate a MessageDifferencer instance? Also if I want to do a diff for different orders, I have to set to TreatAsSet for the field but that seems to be cumbersome as there are many many fields in the messages I'm trying to compare. Do you have thoughts on how I can do that for the fields?

Comment: Yes you need to instantiate it, e.g. `MessageDifferencer dif; std::string res; dif.ReportDifferencesToString(&res); bool res = dif.Compare(message1, message2); if(res) { std::cout << "SAME!"; } else { std::cout << "DIFFERENT: " << res; }` The [ordering of repeated fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional) is guaranteed to remain consistent with respect to each other, so unless the repeated fields got serialized in a different order in the two messages they should compare equal out of the box.

Comment: So it depends on how you're using repeated fields - if it's not just a list (where order matters) - you'll have to cue protobuf in on how it should be diffed (e.g. `TreatAsSet()`, `TreatAsMap()`, etc...) Example: `message Ints { repeated int32 values = 1; }` - if values is `[1, 2, 3]` for message1 and `[1, 3, 2]` for message2 are they equal? `AS_LIST`: false   / `AS_SET`: true

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I can get the differing fields printer. The problem though is that MessageDifferencer treats different ordering fields as differing messages. I think serialization might not be done the same way either. There are std::unordered_maps in the datastructures that are being serialized and I suspect that might lead to different ordering. Is there a way to make MessageDifferencer go through key/value pairs and compare them? If not, I'll have to write my own differencer? Not sure if TreatAsSet makes a difference if the field is not "repeated" and just differently ordered?

Comment: Seems like setting TreatAsSet doesn't make a difference either. Please let me know if there is any standard option other than implementing my own MessageDifferencer.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is unordered, so the order in which the fields will end up in the message is unspecified for those repeated fields. - To get those working you'd have to treat them as maps (`TreatAsMap` / `TreatAsMapWithMultipleFieldsAsKey`, etc...) with the appropriate key column(s).

Comment: Also please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.